# A switch statement doesn't work when the equivalent if statement does

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement, conditional-statements, string-evaluation

```
switch(type)
{
    case 'home':
         console.log('home switch');
         break;
}
```

The above code does not write out to the console, neither does the following:

```
switch(type)
{
     case "home":
         console.log('home switch');
         break;
}
```

The following, however, does:

```
if (type == 'home')
{
     console.log('home if');
}
```

I don't have a clue why. This isn't a show-stopper, I can use the `if` statement instead, but I'm genuinely curious as to why this is the case.

NOTE: These statements are a straight replace, nothing else to consider here. No change in scope, no code I'm not mentioning that could be interfering with the value of `type`.

Comment: what is the type of `type`? Is it a string? an object?

Comment: what is the exact value of type, are u putting value in type dynamically?

Comment: It works for me both codes: http://jsfiddle.net/nG7KG/

Comment: Apologies for not clarifying, `type` is a string.

Comment: How do you set the value of type?

Comment: For testing purposes, `type = 'home';`

Comment: Are you actually using the string `home`? or is it really a different value?

Comment: I copied your code exactly into the Firebug console and set `type = "home"`, as you stated, and it fired the `console.log()` statement in all three instances.  Have you tried checking out `console.log(type)` right before the `switch` to see what the value is?

Comment: since each case is an executed expression, you can easily "overload" switch to do any kind of compare:  switch(true){ case type=="home" : ... }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not the equivalent if-statement. The [`switch` statement](http://es5.github.io/#x12.11) is specified to use the [strict equality](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.6) `===` operator.

Comment: I didn't realize this. I've just changed my `if` to use `===` and, as you'd expect, it hasn't met the condition. I don't really understand what's happened here though, it's merely a string - surely `===` would be satisfied? If not, how else do you switch case a string?

Comment: @DeeMac: Looks like it's not then. Please make a demo with an example value for `type`. Also test `console.log(typeof type)`.

Comment: This is not a solution to OP question but i learned something today!

Comment: You might try `switch(String(type)) { … }` then.

Comment: @laaposto: Until the OP shows more of his code, I cannot offer a "solution". It does answer the question "*I don't have a clue why*" though :-)